# Make the VS Code move the curly brace to the next line automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to make the VS Code move the curly brace to the next line automatically?

E.g. in this code:

```
namespace MyNamesp
{
    public class Configuration {

    }
}
```

I would like the code to be formatted like this:

```
namespace MyNamesp
{
    public class Configuration 
    {

    }
}
```

ASAP as I typed this:

```
namespace MyNamesp
{
    public class Configuration {}
}
```

And pressed (or not pressed, I do not care about this exactly) the `Enter` while being between the `{}`.

Right now in order to achieve this kind of formatting I have to select the whole document (`Ctrl` + `A`) and click `Alt` + `Shift` + 'F'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode format curly brackets on the same line c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136015/vscode-format-curly-brackets-on-the-same-line-c-sharp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56934072/109941

Comment: @JimG., the  stackoverflow.com/q/56934072/109941 answer do not help. Thank you.

Comment: @JimG., [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136015/vscode-format-curly-brackets-on-the-same-line-c-sharp) solution does not work either. Thank you.

Comment: @JimG.'s duplicate is valid. After you have created the `omnisharp json`, click `Alt`+`shift` + `F`. Works!

Comment: @panoskarajohn As noted in the question, the OP doesn't want to have to type `Alt`+`Shift`+`F` but have it happen automatically.

Comment: Did you create the `omnisharp json` with everything set to `true`?

Comment: Do you have the Text Editor settings for Format on Type and Format on Paste enabled?

Comment: I would recommend you type in `namespace MyNamesp` then press `Enter`, then press `{` then press `Enter` to get what you want. You should not be typing space after e.g. `Configuration` if you want the open brace on a newline, you should be typing `Enter`. You can also enable Format on Save to have it reformat every time you save a file.

Comment: @NetMage, over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136015/vscode-format-curly-brackets-on-the-same-line-c-sharp) the opposite is recommended. It is recommended to set everything to `false`. But ok, let me try to set everything to `true`.

Comment: @NetMage, it does not work with the `omnisharp` even when all the properties are set to `true`.

Comment: @NetMage, hm. The solution to press the `Enter` first seems very clever in this case. Could you, please, post it as an answer?

Comment: That question is asking the opposite of yours, the answer is how to prevent a newline before braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would help if you turned on the Text Editor settings for Format on Type and Format on Paste. You could also turn on Format on Save if desired.

I would recommend you type in `namespace MyNamesp` then press `Enter`, then press `{` then press `Enter` to get what you want. You should not be typing `space` after e.g. `Configuration` if you want the open brace on a newline, you should be typing `Enter`.